# How to check if AVCaptureDeviceFormat supports Slow Motion recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I was looking around to implement slow mo video recording. I found that we can do it by configuring `AVCaptureDevice's activeFormat` property.

I have the code for getting the highest frame rate possible. But what if I want to fix the resolution, so that the slow-mo will happen but only above a certain resolution. I don't want low resolution slow-mo videos.

I tested on 5s and it gives the below as highest frame rate:

```
Format: <AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x174006680 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 720, { 3-120 fps}, fov:58.080, binned, supports vis, max zoom:52.00 (upscales @1.16), AF System:1, ISO:34.0-1088.0, SS:0.000012-0.333333>

Range: <AVFrameRateRange: 0x17400a5a0 3 - 120>
```

Question1: How to check if current device supports slow motion recording?

Question2: What if I want to have 1280x720 as my threshold. So that if in future, apple makes a device, which supports same 3-120 fps but has lower resolution? I wouldn't want my video quality to suffer.

Question3: Once I set this `activeFormat` property, How can I rollback to the default frame rate?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)configureCameraForHighestFrameRate:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormat = nil;
    AVFrameRateRange *bestFrameRateRange = nil;
    for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats] ) {
        for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
            if ( range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameRate ) {
                bestFormat = format;
                bestFrameRateRange = range;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( bestFormat ) {
        if ( [device lockForConfiguration:NULL] == YES ) {
            device.activeFormat = bestFormat;
            device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration;
            device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration;
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get good quality slow motion video at the range of minimum 120fps.
So You can check it by

```
device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration.timescale >= 120
```

NB: check it before you manually replace the value.

Comment: could you please provide some reference for this? I actually need to make up some statistical data. Or I have to check in every device.